What's the difference between "Model detail" and "Texture detail" in Portal 1?
I'm trying to understand the Portal 1 Video Settings a bit better.

What's the difference between "Model detail" and "Texture detail" in Portal 1?
What counts as models and what counts as textures?
Could anyone shed some light on these two video settings please?

Model detail is the detail of the polygons used to form the 3D model

Texture detail is the detail of the texture used to paint the model


The answer from Nathan Goings is correct and wonderfully succinct, please do give an upvote there.
However, there’s a bit more to actually understanding all of this and it’s too much to fit in a comment, hence why this answer exists.

Texture detail is easy to explain. It’s just a matter of the resolution of the textures that are being used for rendering. Higher values increase the two-dimensional detail of every surface in the game, at the cost of needing more video RAM and more processing power to render. Almost everything you can see in any modern game has a texture. Some games may opt to render with simple color fills (or gradients) on surfaces instead of textures, either for performance/space reason (common on early 3-D games such as you would see on the Nintendo 64 or the PlayStation 2), or for stylistic reasons (seen occasionally in more modern games, usually to replicate the visual style of early 3-D games). I am not aware of any such rendering in Portal 1, AFAIK everything there renders with a texture.
Model detail is a bit trickier to explain. Almost every properly 3-dimensional object you see in a video game has an associated 3-D model constructed from simple polygonal faces (usually triangles, though others are possible). These models just define the surfaces the textures are rendered on, not what shows up there. A higher level of model detail means that smaller polygonal faces are used to construct the model, which makes surfaces look smoother and reduces three-dimensional aliasing of small details (IOW, it lets you accurately recreate smaller details), again at the cost of using more video RAM and more processing power for rendering.
As a general rule, texture detail has a bigger impact on video RAM usage than model detail, but model detail has a bigger effect on processing requirements than texture detail.
It’s unusual these days to find games that let you control the two parameters independently, as the main use case (providing good support for systems with very limited video RAM but a very fast GPU, or with very large amounts of video RAM but a very slow GPU) is significantly less relevant than it used to be. The norm now is to tie both settings to the overall ‘quality’ setting that most games expose, or not let them be adjusted at all.

I wouldn't say "unusual" by far! Maybe it depends on the genres of games one is more invested in, but in my experience most 3D games still allow separate control of texture and model detail (sometimes using different terminology, of course, that might or might not entirely be the same thing—model and texture quality tend to be more common nowadays, I believe).

@Joachim I must just be missing the ones that do then. Almost all ‘new’ games I’ve seen recently don’t have separate controls for them, though they may have separate controls for different types of objects.

A lot might have more focused parameters like 'object details', 'terrain details', 'NPC details' and other, more focused model detail settings. 'Viewing distance' is related to this as well.

@Joachim But those controls will also generally effect texture detail, for that specific class of model. We've shifted from a world where the controls are based on what sort of rendering activity you are adjusting, to what sort of game object is being fed to that rendering pipeline.

This is a portal gun comparison for Portal 2, but I think it could work since it's the same game engine.
As you can see, when models are more detailed edges on the gun are smoother, also the floor tiles are clearer. The "Aperture" sticker is a texture, and has a better definition.
Above lowest quality, below high quality:

As @Nathan correctly wrote, model detail specify the detail of the polygons, and you can see it better on curved surfaces. More detail means more polygons, because every model is built by triangles.
Textures are the graphics covering the models, they add colors, materials and small details.
EDIT:
As requested, I made a comparison on Portal with different settings:

above is high model details and low texture details
below is low model details and high texture details


As you can see, lower model details make curved surfaces very polygonal and not smooth.
While better texture details make surfaces more clean and realistic, on the other hand on low details there are some undefined stains on things. Blue particles are better, too. And, as previously written, the Aperture sticker is perfectly readable with high details.

So the floor isn't a texture? Kind of surprised there. At least the way this is worded indicates the floor is a model

@TimmyJim it's definitely a model, in other rooms you can see that not all tiles are at the same level, showing irregular shadows between them

The images would be much more helpful if it was only changing one setting at a time, showing both on low then both on high doesn't really highlight the difference.

@TimmyJim: Everything you can see in any reasonable, modern 3D game (i.e. not Doom or other early 3D games of similar vintage) has both a model and a texture. Some models or textures are very simple, but they're always present, because there would otherwise be nothing to render (and then you wouldn't be able to see it).

@Kevin probably includes the word "modern" because it was common for early 3D games (think: classic FFVII or other games on the first PlayStation) to include some models without textures to conserve space and memory. These low-poly meshes were colored simplistically using vertex shading, which appeared as color gradations. The gradient stops were at the corners of the polygons, so you could have a triangle with a slightly different color in each of its 3 corners and it would look a little more detailed than just a solid-color triangle.

@Mentalist: Well, that and the fact that Doom makes use of sprite graphics and... whatever you want to call its bespoke system for rendering lines and sectors.

@TimmyJim Most floors in most games (especially in the time of Portal (2)) are too simple to have any discernible model detail. Floors in Source Engine games (and many others) usually just consist of single brushes, textured with a visible material on one side (while the others aren't even rendered in-game). It has no LODs, so model detail has no bearing on them (while 'texture detail' obviously does).

Nitpick: I believe the Aperture logo is simply part of the gun's texture. Not only does it make more sense as drawing transparent decals is more expensive, but you can see the compression artifacts surrounding the logo on the gun material.

regarding the floor: games can create the illusion of depth using textures as a "height map". In the screen shots above, the floor is a model or geometry of some sort, but the finer detail there is a texture. Same for the gloss on the gun and the distressed cracking wear marks. A special texture is used where they use brightness of a pixel to determine it's height offset from the surface. See, for example: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterHeightMap.html

@DBS done, is it better for you?

@Yorik Normal maps, usually. But that's 'texture detail' :) Height maps are used in case of tessellation (which combines both settings, but usually has a dedicated setting, because it's much more demanding a technique).
